# Oracle Enterprise Manager Installation

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle-enterprise-manager

First I install oracle 11g database with this configuration

`Step 2 of 9`

I selected `Create and configure a database`

`Step 3 of 9`

I selected `Desktop Class`

`Step 4 of 8`

Global database name: `Blitz`

Administrative password: `Pass1234`

After that it gives me this information

Global Database Name: `Bliz`

System Identified(SID): `Blitz`

Server Parameter File name: C:\app\annie\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3\database\spfileBlitz.ora

The Database Control URL is `https://localhost:5501/em`

Management Repository has been placed in secure mode wherein Enterprise Manager data will be encrypted.
The encryption key has been placed in the file: `C:/app/annie/product/11.2.0/dbhome_3/localhost_Blitz/sysman/config/emkey.ora.`
Please ensure this file is backed up as the encrypted data will become unusable if this file is lost.

Then configure this:

```
Username - Password

SYS      - Pass1234

SYSTEM   - Pass1234
```

---

Then I try to install Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c

First in Command Prompt I enter the following command to get the host name:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

`select host_name from v$instance`

that gives me `PC1`

Then in `Step 6 of 9` of Enterprise Manager Installation

I provide the following for Database Connection Details

Database Host Name: `PC1`

Port: `1523`

Serivice/SID: `Blitz`

SYS Password: `Pass1234`

But I got this error

`There was a problem connecting to the database on the host and port specified. Check to make sure the host is up or that the database listener is running on that host.`

So I tried tried  to changed the Database Host Name to `localhost`

But I got this error

`Enterprise Manager Database Control schema exists in the database. To proceed with the installation of Enterprise Manager Cloud Control, you must deconfigure the same by running the following command:`

`To deconfigure Database Control for a single instance database, do the following command on database host:
 (a) Set the environment variable <ORACLE_HOME> to the database home.(b) Run the following command:
<Database ORACLE HOME>/bin/emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop -SYS_PWD <sys password> -SYSMAN_PWD <sysman password>`

`To deconfigure Database Control for an Real Application Clusters (RAC) database, do the following command on database host:
(a) Set the environment variable <ORACLE_HOME> to the database home.(b) Run the following command:
<Database ORACLE HOME>/bin/emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop -cluster -SYS_PWD <sys password> -SYSMAN_PWD <sysman password>`

`NOTE: If the existing database is on different host, then install Oracle Management Agent on the database host, to monitor the database.`

So in Command Prompt I enter this command:

`set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\annie\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3`

`C:\app\annie\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3\bin\emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop -cluster -SYS_PWD Pass123 -SYSMAN_PWD Pass123`

Then it ask me for the details so I input the details.

Database Unique Name: `Blitz`

Service Name: `Blitz`

Listner port number: `1523`

Listener Home_Oracle: `C:\app\annie\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3`

But I go this error:

[image]

---

And I'm now stack up with this. Please Help.

Comment: Why port 1523 ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the    `-cluster -` option ? 
Is you database repository part of a cluster ?

Make sure first that you can connect to the database using the tns names.

**Example :**

```
sqlplus system/password@'tns_identified'
```

*Then to deconfig you em repo :*
**Try using this syntax :**

```
 emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop -SYS_PWD oracle -SYSMAN_PWD oracle
```

[For some nice articles on how you can prepare you Oracle Enterprise Grid Control Monitoring environment check the link](http://www.aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=999&page=oem&id_tit=15)